# Can I remember a proxy password in Firefox 3.6.12?

Tags: firefox, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let Firefox automatically accept “authentication required” dialogue](https://superuser.com/questions/249292/let-firefox-automatically-accept-authentication-required-dialogue)

I'm using a proxy and when I start a browser and visit first page, I see the prompt for the password. I've saved it before in Firefox, and the form is prefilled and I need only click "Login". But I don't want to see this prompt and start Firefox with preconfigured proxy:passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [FoxyProxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org/) can help.  I've used it for years; it's very stable.

Answer (score 0):

To save proxy username and password in firefox do the following:

1. Go to Options → Security
2. Check "Remember password for sites"
3. Click on Exceptions and remove all or remove proxy site from the list
4. Restart Firefox