# How can I make Firefox remember my proxy's username and password?

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox with a proxy. Every time I restart the browser, I have to enter the proxy's username and password.

**Is there any way to get Firefox to remember the username and password and send it automatically so I don't have to type it in manually?**

NTLM won't help as the proxy is unrelated to my Windows set-up.

I see this question was [already asked](https://superuser.com/questions/215310/can-i-remember-a-proxy-password-in-firefox-3-6-12). The accepted answer was to use FoxyProxy. This didn't solve my problem, however, as I was still prompted for the username and password the first time in the browsing session that I needed to use the proxy.

[image: Prompt]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for the password prompt?  The default proxy auth dialog for firefox includes a checkbox to remember the password, so perhaps it is a prompt from the proxy itself.

Comment: @Paul: I told Firefox to remember the password, and it did - it just displays the prompt filled-in. I still have to hit 'enter', though. Is there a way to not even have to do that? (I ask for automation purposes, but consider me an impatient user if that helps =P). It is definitely a prompt from the proxy itself.. I'd just like Firefox to remember the details + send them without asking me.

Comment: Sure - my point is that the proxy auth prompt in ff will remember the details and normally not prompt once remembered. If it is a webform presented by the proxy, then the approach would be different.  A screenshot would help identify which is occuring.

Comment: @Paul: updated the question. That's what I saw when I just turned on firefox and typed in an address. (Sometimes I get one with a checkbox to get password manager to remember the password, but it's already checked.) I didn't see what you meant by whether the proxy did it, but yea it's not a web-form.

Comment: Hmm.  Yeah, that is a proxy auth dialog rather than a form.  I think this might be the way the proxy is set up for auth, as I have a similar situation and I get that prompt once in a while, not every startup.  Perhaps autohotkey is the answer.

Comment: In the Firefox Preferences dialog, on the Security tab, make sure the "Remember password for sites" checkbox is checked.  If this is cleared, Firefox never offers to remember passwords (including proxy and basic auth passwords).

Answer (score 5):

1. Browse to `about:config` in Firefox
2. Click on "I'll be carefull, I promise!"
3. Search `signon.autologin.proxy` and `network.websocket.enabled` in the *Search Input Box* then change their values as follow:

   ```
   signon.autologin.proxy=true
   network.websocket.enabled=false
   ```
4. Restart Firefox, input user name and password for your proxy and click *Remember*.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the steps to getting to these settings? Some users/visitors may not know about `about:config` or how to get to it.

Comment: The first setting makes sense, but the second one actually disables a technology which had a bug in this area that now [seems to be fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766817). Maybe correct the answer if the situation has indeed changed?

Comment: This did not work for me as I do not see any "remember my password" checkbox option.

Comment: `network.websocket.enabled` doesn't exist in my updated windows firefox

Comment: `network.websocket.enabled` also doesn't exist in my Firefox 67 on Ubuntu. `signon.autologin.proxy` is set to true, but Firefox still shows password promts at startup.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to let Firefox (v103) remember the proxy credentials by (temporally) enable *Settings > Security tab > Logins and Passwords > Ask to save logins and passwords for websites* (formerly *"Remember password for sites"* as reported in other answers); the corresponding user setting is `signon.rememberSignons = true`.

If you then provide the credentials for your proxy, Firefox will ask to save them (in a follow-up popup).

An alternative for this process is to add the login manually using the *Saved Logins* button (i.e., the `about:logins` page): Click *Create New Login* and enter:

- Web site address: `moz-proxy://<your proxy URL>:<and port>`
- Username
- Password

Answer (score 0):

Proxy password problem in Mozilla Firefox 3 - SOLVED by accident :)

1. Start Firefox 3
2. In Address bar write "about:config"
3. In filter write network.auth.use-sspi
4. Double click on "true" and it should become "false"
5. If things does not become better write here to give
   other changes I made. So far nothing else worked until this change

Try it. It might solve your problem. Credits to Revell

Answer (score 0):

The answer that fixed the issue for me was buried in a hidden comment from William, so I'll paste it here for others:

In the Firefox Preferences dialog, on the Security tab, make sure the "Remember password for sites" checkbox is checked. If this is cleared, Firefox never offers to remember passwords (including proxy and basic auth passwords)

Answer (score 0):

If "Remember password for sites" is already checked but not working, uncheck & recheck it. Really. Apparently the display default isn't necessarily the same as the behavior; on several brand new users (FF66 on Ubuntu; FF created profile on 1st launch) that I set up, I couldn't get it to save the proxy credentials, but as soon as I unchecked/checked the setting, it worked properly.